# How could I import an external jar library to ZEPPELIN in Hortonworks?

Tags: python, import, jar, dependencies, pyspark

I have an HDP 2.5 cluster and I am working with ZEPPELIN's %pyspark interpreter to generate code.

I want to use a library that helps working with Time Series Analysis in Spark both in python, java and scala, which is specified here: https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries

The problem is that I don't know how to import and use this library to my ZEPPELIN %pyspark interpreter.

First of all, I downloaded the .jar file named "sparkts-0.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar". Next, I save it in my /opt/ directory in my cluster node where ZEPPELIN is working.

Then, I tried by using %dep, but it's deprecated in my current version of HDP, so I added a dependency in the ZEPPELIN "interpreters" menu, this way:

[image]

I restarted the interpreter and tried in a ZEPPELIN notebook:

```
%pyspark

import sparkts
```

But I got an error:

```
ImportError: No module named sparkts
```

So my question is: How could I import and use this .jar file to make Time Series analysis in my HDP cluster with ZEPPELIN?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since its a Python library, you need to PIP install this on each node of your cluster if you're running zeppelin on top of a cluster using a resource manager like YARN where jobs could run on any node of the cluster and you're using an interpreter like Livy to distribute your job. If the library isn't available through PIP you can install it by running setup.py (if it has one) or as a last resort supply jar file directly to Pyspark shell like so spark-shell --jars  (not a solution for Zeppelin though)